# Retrofit POST request drops all parameters

Tags: android, node.js, rest, post, retrofit2

I am trying to use RetroFit to pass a username, score, and day to a Node server to be passed along to a database. I have multiple GET requests working. When I try to make a POST request, it seems to drop all params that I pass in. Even weirder: I've implemented RetroFit POST recently without this issue and my code doesn't seem to be much different this time.

Anyways, here are my relevant code snippets:

**RetroFit.java**

```
public interface RetroFit {

    ...

    @POST("addUserToDatabase")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<JsonObject> addUserToDatabase(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("numberCorrect") int numberCorrect,
            @Field("dayOfTheWeek") String dayOfTheWeek
    );

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    //The below can be done outside the class

    public static final Retrofit retro = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myurl:portnumber")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

}
```

**ResultsActivity**

```
Call<JsonObject> call = this.retroFit.addUserToDatabase(
                username,
                numberOfCorrectAnswers,
                dayOfTheWeek);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                Log.d("addUsersToDatabase", response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("addUsersToDatabase", "FAILED", t);
            }
        });
```

**Note**: username, numberOfCorrectAnswers, and dayOfTheWeek are all generated before this. I am getting no type errors with them.

I get this JsonObject from within the app: 
`{"_id":"5dedd080c3bf4116716162e5"}`

And this JsonObject from PostMan making the same request:

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "numberCorrect": 3,
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Sunday",
    "_id": "5dedd3cbc3bf4116716162e6"
}
```

I've tried simplifying it down to a smaller POST with just one field, but that one still seems to get dropped. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your postman screenshot for this API request

Comment: Do you have `Instant Run` turned on by any chance? Try disabling it and run the project again.

Comment: can you post the code you are getting your post parameters(username,numberCorrect,dayoftheweek)

Comment: 1)port number dosent work in retrofit url
2) if you use android 8+ ,  you must do trust http url

Comment: Does your API accept both `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `Content-Type; application/json`?